# What does this symbol of a PNP BJT transistor with extra connections to the base and collector represent?

Tags: bjt, schematics, pnp, pll

I am trying to understand the internal circuit schematic of the LM565 phase locked loop IC, on page 6 of this datasheet: [PDF Datasheet for LM565 from TI website](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm565.pdf)

In the upper middle, there is a strange little symbol labeled "Q13". Here is a screenshot: [image: screenshot of strange symbol]

It looks like a PNP BJT, but I am not sure what it is exactly. Can anyone give me a pointer.

Also, this schematics has quite a few BJT with unconnected pins. I assume that this is when a BJT is used as a diode, but if someone could shed some light I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Tetrode transistor.

Comment: The data sheet that you linked from the TI web site does not have any chip level schematic. The page has been rendered blank.

Comment: That's probably your viewer - it displays perfectly fine in evince.

Comment: @MichaelKaras : I'm using Chrome to view it, and it works fine. Might there be a problem with your PDF viewer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a multi collector transistor. More common is the multi emitter transistor used in TTL integrated circuits.

[image]

Comment: I can see how that can indeed be a multi-collector transistor, but then what is that wire coming out of the base and ... is it connected to one of the collector then ???

Comment: @blondiepassesby: It's a third collector that's tied to the base.

Comment: @blondiepassesby Looks like its internally connected as a diode to me. If you look at the circuit they have several transistors connected in this fashion.